# I want to convert pdf to image to pdf using rmagick in rails and then upload using activestorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

```
pdf = Magick::ImageList.new(self.checklist_question.resource_file.service_url) do
      self.quality = 100
    end
```

This converts the pdf to images but does not get the point on how to save and merge them in pdf again and then upload to active storage.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a different gem like carrier_wave and write the data as explained here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit as it looks irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @JawadAkram you can get the binary data, write the data to a file.

Comment: This does not answer the question while, which clearly states usage of activestorage. and yes we could go low-level and start doing manual stuff with binary data, but I think activestorage + rmagic have interfaces specific that do this for you. the question is how and which?

Comment: I suggested a way to solve the problem, I'm not sure if there's a built-in way to do this. Probably.